# JDBC batch use "CASE WHEN" in insert statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I wonder if something like this is possible:

```
PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE(DATE,VALUE) VALUES (?, (CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE ? END))");
stm.setDate(1, date);
stm.setString(2, value);
//stm.setString(3, value); -> without this
stm.addBatch();
....
stm.executeBatch();
```

Because of total 3 "?" in insert string it's needed to add another `stm.setString(3, value)`.

1. Is it possible to avoid setting value again -> `stm.setString(3, value)`?
   if yes, what is the correct syntax?
2. Is it allowed to do such operations for batch?

This is working for me:

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE(DATE,VALUE) VALUES (TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')), ?)"
```

But what about more complicated statements like `CASE WHEN` ...etc?

I know for this case it's better to use default column value, like:

```
VALUE  CHAR(1)   default 'N'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) to avoid repeating the parameter value

```
NVL(?, 'N')
```

> NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string in the results of a query.

P.S. For more complicated statements you can use [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) as

```
  decode(?, null, 'N', 'SOMEVALUE','REPLACEVALUE', 'DEFAULTVALUE')
```

Comment: Not to mention this can be done easier by just adding an `if` clause to the code to see whether the parameter is null or not. No need to trouble the database with anything.

Comment: Other databases use `coalesce` instead of `nvl`

Comment: Thank you. DECODE looks great -> for one value. What if sql like this:
"INSERT INTO TABLE(VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, XXX) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CASE WHEN ? = 'ABC' THEN 'AAA' WHEN ? = 'CDE' THEN 'CCC' WHEN ? = 'YES' THEN 'EEE' END)"

Comment: @Martin You can have nested decode as `decode(?, 'ABC' ,'AAA', decode(?, 'CDE' ,'CCC' , decode(?, ...)))`

Comment: yes, it is true. But in that case my code will look like: stm.setString(1, value1);
stm.setString(2, value2);
stm.setString(3, value3);
stm.setString(4, value1);
stm.setString(5, value2);
stm.setString(6, value3); Am I right? (6times "?" = 6times stm.setString())

Is it possible to reduce last three setString (4-6) ? is it possible to refer to already inserted value setString (1-3)